# In Javascript strict mode can you assign arguments to another var?

Tags: javascript, strict

I'm trying to validate Javascript code through Sonar and I have some doubts about *strict mode* rules.

The rule I'm validating is about ["eval" and "arguments" behavior in strict mode](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-2532?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel).

In reading this rule description, it seems I can not assign *arguments* to new variable for accessing it later or in a loop.

On reading some documentation, from [strict mode on Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode#Making_eval_and_arguments_simpler) and [strict mode on IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/br230269%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) the rules I found basically are (that apply to this case):

1. I can't have any variables/functions/etc named *arguments* since this is a reserved word.
2. *arguments* can't be bound

But, **the sample code above seems to be violating that Sonar rule**:

```
var args = arguments;
```

So, **is this a false-positive or is this piece of code violating strict mode**?

Comment: Why do you think this is validating the rule?

Comment: I think it's not violating `strict mode`, you can have it.

Comment: It doesn't violate, you can check it yourself in console in developer tools.

Comment: @dbarnes because Sonar is accusing that saying I'm modifying *arguments* https://www.dropbox.com/s/xfpuqp1wj2shzg4/Screenshot%202013-11-21%2015.44.49.png

Comment: @vorrtex I did check. But I asked here because I wanted to be 100% sure I was not violating before submitting a defect to that Sonar rule.

Comment: var `args = arguments` binds `args`, not `arguments`.  The Sonar page you linked forbids binding `arguments`, and it seems to agree with the ECMAScript5 spec. (http://www.ecmascript.org/docs/tc39-2009-043.pdf, page 233)

Comment: @psquared yet Sonar is using that rule and getting a false-positive with `var args = arguments` and that is a defect, right?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it's just being safe and not checking to see if args is used anywhere. I bet they made the assumption that args will be altered so you can't assign arguments to anything.

Comment: Just wondering, what happens if you do `var args = [].prototype.slice.call(arguments);`? I'm asking because without calling (e.g.) `slice`, `args` will point to the same object as `arguments`, so modifying `args` will modify `arguments`. And maybe you're doing that in your code, or maybe the rule is being cautious here.

Comment: @dbarnes most likely. But, could also be a false-positive.

Comment: @IngoBürk I pasted the actual code. I'm not doing slice. But this seems to work fine for me `var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);` on _strict mode_.

Comment: I know you weren't using `slice`, I was suggesting doing it to see if the sonar warning goes away. I always `slice` an `arguments` object anyway since it is no normal array (but this converts it into one). Does your last comment mean it does actually make the warning disappear?

Comment: @IngoBürk I can't change the code to re-validate Sonar because that is production code. But I can test on any browser. Both examples (slicing or not) works fine with _strict mode_. Also, as 2 people here said, it does comply with _strict mode_ since _arguments_ is not being modified.

Comment: @IngoBürk on thing, for sure, is that if you assign _arguments_ to _args_ you can't modify _args_ too.

Comment: I get that it complies and that it will **work**. I am wondering whether with using `slice` it would now **validate**, just to figure out if that's what the rule is "afraid" of. Too bad you don't have a testing environment to re-validate. But yes, it is valid either way, so no matter for what reason the validation fails, it is a false-positive. You should consider opening an issue report against Sonar.

Comment: @IngoBürk *I don't have yet*, but I could change the source and test in a couple days. Meaning Sonar is not yet fully integrated to the process and I'm building/customizing those Javascript rules.
I will try to, but I couldn't create an account on their Jira, so I'll have to see if they have another bug tracking tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the users answers and some researches, **I've found this code** (`var args = arguments;`) **to be valid**, since it's not modifying arguments, but only assigning it to another variable.

Please note that, since `args` now points to `arguments` it can't be modified also. But it can be read normally.

**Update:** [Fix will be available](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-3328) under new release Javascript plugin (1.5).